# CKEditor - tab and shift-tab to indent and unindent block

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to get TAB + SHIFT_TAB to work in CK Editor

My extraPlugins have `indent,indentlist,indentblock` and list indents are working.

But if I select a paragraph, the indent icon lights up, but pressing tab does nothing.  If I add `tabSpaces = 4` to the config then I get 4 spaces rather than an indent?

Any suggestions on how to make it work like Word etc?

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you found the solution/workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing in the CKEditor website and bug reporting, as of version 4.5 using Tab/Shift-Tab key to provide

- Move to next/previous table cell, if with a table
- Move to next editor instance in a page otherwise

Requires a [plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/tab).

The issue seems to have been around a while since CKEditor bug [#10605](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10605) was from three years ago dealing with this very problem you are describing and CKEditor bug #8244 was opened 5 years ago and closed 3 years ago.

Indent documentation states

> Registers content-specific commands as a part of the indentation system directed by generic commands....

This doesn't appear to do what you are expecting as results. This is the same case with indentlist

I would have given more links but not able to at this point to support my answer here. But the best solution to your problem does seem to be using the tabs plugin.